# Java comparator type-variable problems?

Tags: java, comparator

Im trying to implement a comparator for a custom class so I can choose which field to sort by. one of the comparator classes I made is giving me an error I do not understand in the slightest. feel free to point out anything you see, beacause my boss left early on friday and I didn't get to ask him questions once I started trying to sort an array of the "Spectrum" objects in the code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class scanComparator<Spectrum> implements Comparator<Spectrum> {
    public int compare(Spectrum o1, Spectrum o2){
        int s1 = o1.getScanNumber();
        int s2 = o2.getScanNumber();
        int eval = s2 - s1;
        return eval;
    }
}
```

this is the error (from jGrasp):

```
scanComparator.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        int s2 = o2.getScanNumber();
                   ^
  symbol:   method getScanNumber()
  location: variable o2 of type Spectrum
  where Spectrum is a type-variable:
    Spectrum extends Object declared in class scanComparator
```

getScanNumber() is public and not miss-spelled. I re copy-pasted the method name from the Spectrum class. the same error is given for o1 but ommitted because its redundant.

Comment: this would seem the most likley explination however odd that it would not point out the same for o1.

Comment: sorry should have specified these points ill make an edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are declaring `scanComparator<Spectrum>`, just change it to 'scanComparator' as follow and everything goes fine.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class scanComparator implements Comparator<Spectrum> {
    public int compare(Spectrum o1, Spectrum o2){
        int s1 = o1.getScanNumber();
        int s2 = o2.getScanNumber();
        int eval = s2 - s1;
        return eval;
    }
}
```

Comment: how bout that. I thought I did the same for the other comparators but now that I look at my code i did not. Astute observation, thank you

Comment: That's a painfully verbose way to write `return o1.getScanNumber() - o2.getScanNumber();`.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
public class scanComparator<Spectrum> implements Comparator<Spectrum> {
```

should be

```
public class ScanComparator implements Comparator<Spectrum> {
```

The first `<Spectrum>` was not the name of the class, it was an unbound type variable, basically equivalent to `Object`, and of course `Object` has no such method. This type variable was being used for the types of the parameters to `compare()`. Removing that invalid specification will allow the real type name `Spectrum` to be used.